# Jira → Agile → Scrum Board → Work—change text of column titles?

Tags: jira

Jira → Agile → Scrum Board → Work has columns with these titles:

- To Do
- In Progress
- Done

Can the text for these titles be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 6 of Greenhopper (Agile) and probably earlier versions, you can do this by going to the Scrum Board, then selecting `Tools` > `Configure` from the menu on the right. Then select the `Columns` tab if it isn't already and you should then be able to in-line edit the titles by clicking on them.